# rails 3.0.5 issue with nil variables!

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a variable in my partial called title. If I do:

```
<% if title.nil? %>
  # stuff here
<% end %>
```

Then I get an error that title in not a known variable or method! What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is not defined then you'll get this error.

A variable in a partial can be defined by passing it as a local variable:

```
<%= render :partial => 'my_partial', :locals => { :title => 'My Title' } %>
```

Or by defining it in the partial:

```
<% title = nil %>
<% if title.nil? %>
  # Do stuff here.
<% end %>
```

You can also use instance variables in your partial, like `@title` and they don't need to be defined because they will always default to nil.

If you want to check if your variable is defined, then do the following:

```
<% if defined?(title) %>
  # Do stuff here.
<% end %>
```

Comment: In Rails 3, you can do `<%= render 'my_partial' :title => 'My Title' %>` instead of the longer variant mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your variable defined? If it is set in a controller it should be an instance variable, which is prepended with `@` like `@title`.
If `title` is actually declared in your partial, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: title is not declared at all... uptill rails 3.0.3 if it was not declared the code worked...